# How to compile something using arm-none-eabi-gcc on windows

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to build a project for a raspberry pi 4, using windows 10 as the building platform, I have the compiler installed, `arm-none-eabi-gcc` however every piece of information I've learned about it relates to how to run it on a linux machine, and I don't really want to run a vm just to load the linux environment, so how do I run the compiler on windows 10, Do I run it from Cmd? or is there a different method to do this?

Comment: Do you target a 32 bit version of Linux ? a 64 bit version ? or do you want to write a bare-metal application ? if yes,  a 32 bit or a 64 bit one ? Please update your question accordingly, you may get faster/better answers to your question..

Comment: always good to play in the sandbox first before creating your own sandbox, there are countless windows gnu tool solutions which you should be able to find, but even easier if you can run windows you can run linux on the same computer, without installing anything on the hard drive, to get your feet wet.  you can also get a second pi or develop on the pi you have.  the pi is simply just another computer there isnt anything magic about it.  use it like a computer.   this is a massively broad question though, so more detail is needed

Comment: once you know what you want to work on and are able to use the tools then you can figure out which set of tools you want on windows, then either just download and install or build from sources and run those commands on windows.

Comment: Knowing the exact model of Raspberry Pi you are using would help as well.

Comment: I am intending to get a raspberry pi 4 in the near future, and outside that, I have absolutely no clue what I am doing, and I am planning on testing in a "sandbox" first, but I still have no idea how to use the compiler.

Comment: Have you considered just compiling on the Raspberry Pi 4 itself? That way you don't need to have a cross-compilation setup.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I have in fact thought of that, and I would do it if I presently had the pi.

Comment: @RWolfe what build tool does your project use? compiler/linker to be used when building can be passed e.g. to cmake/make. And if you installed the compiler on your system you may compile a simple hello world by simply invoking your arm-none-eabi-gcc on your main.c (ofc from cmd.exe or powershell)

Comment: @Frant it says it right there, arm-**NONE**-eabi-gcc, none as in bare-metal

Comment: @Mrmudkip Sometime people are using the wrong toolchain, this is why I was asking for more, non-ambiguous information. If he wants to write A32 or T32 bare-metal code for a Cortex-A72, yes, arm-none-eabi-gcc would be the right toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

You could check this [PreBuilt GNU Toolchain](https://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/) for building natively on Win10. 
Otherwise you could also setup a [WSL environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) in your win10, then you would also be able use any linux toolchains.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the IDE `DS-5 Community Edition`
https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/legacy-tools/ds-5-development-studio/editions/community-edition

You can download the toolchains:
https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads

Then follow the steps in this tutorial:
https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/legacy-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/tutorials/getting-started-with-ds-5-ce-and-armv8-foundation-platform

https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/b/tools-software-ides-blog/posts/running-bare-metal-software-on-the-raspberry-pi-3-using-arm-ds-5

Comment: At first glance the DS-5 Community Edition appears deprecated(?)

Answer (score -1):

You should have the arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe for Windows Compile.
Also, you have the linux environment like MinGW and use installed terminal(xterm).
then, you have to copy the .so files into MinGW `/lib` or `/usr/lib` folder under `C:/MinGW`.
Hope this would be helpful for you.

Comment: .so files are the Linux equivalent of Windows .dll, so this basically means that they are not compatible